# Pandas Merge on dataframe while keeping common number of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframe in python I want to concatenate on common column (eg. id)

First Source dataframe is something like this

```
id  | col 
---------
1   | h1
2   | h2
3   | h3 
3   | h33
3   | h333
4   | h4 
6   | h6
```

Target dataframe is

```
id  | col 
---------
1   | h11
2   | h2
3   | h%
3   | h3
4   | h4 
6   | h6
```

Here, the row with `id=3` has duplicates. Source dataframe with `id=3` has three rows & target dataframe with `id=3` has two rows. I want to be able to retain the first common number of rows (i.e two), something like this

```
id  | col 
---------
1   | h1  | h11
2   | h2  | h2 
3   | h3  | h%
3   | h33 | h3
4   | h4  | h4 
6   | h6  | h6
```

I have tried simple merge in pandas like

`pd.concat(source_df , target_df, on="id")`

Is there anything else I can do to achieve this logic?

Answer (score 3):

you can `merge` with `left` or `inner` depends on your need but before this, you should group by id and give row number with `rank` for each id group.

```
import pandas as pd

source_df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,2,3,3,3,4,6] , 'col' : ['h1','h2','h3','h33','h333','h4','h6']})
target_df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,2,3,3,4,6] , 'col' : ['h11', 'h2','h%','h3','h4','h6']})

source_df["rn"] = source_df.groupby('id')['id'].rank(method='first')

target_df["rn"] = target_df.groupby('id')['id'].rank(method='first')

new_df = target_df.merge(source_df, on=['id','rn'] , how='left')
```

Result:

```
   id col_x   rn col_y
0   1   h11  1.0    h1
1   2    h2  1.0    h2
2   3    h%  1.0    h3
3   3    h3  2.0   h33
4   4    h4  1.0    h4
5   6    h6  1.0    h6
```

Answer (score 2):

i think you should use the merge() function

```
pd.merge(source_df, target_df, on="id", how='inner')
```